# Question on quadratic forms

Tags: abstract-algebra, quadratic-forms

I know a theorem which says:

> If a non-singular quadratic form (homogeneous polynomials of degree $2$) over a field $K$ represents zero non-trivially (i.e., there is a nontrivial solution of the equation $F=0$), then it represents all the non-zero elements of field $K$.

A quadratic form $F$ is said to represent $a$ (in $K$) if there exists $x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n$ such that $F(x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n)= a$.

> My question is whether the converse of the theorem is true when char $K=0$.

When $K$ is a finite field of order $3$, then $X^2+Y^2$ contradicts the converse of the theorem.

Comment: So you want to know if a non-singular quadratic form $F$ over a field $K$ of characteristic $0$ so that $\forall y \in \Bbb K^*,\exists x \in \Bbb K ^n, F(x)=y$ verifies $\exists x \in \Bbb K ^n \setminus\{0\}, F(x)=0$?

Answer (score 5):

You can take $x^2$ over $\mathbb{C}$.

Answer (score 3):

field is $\mathbb Q,$ form is $$ w^2 - 2 x^2 + 3 y^2 - 6 z^2.   $$

Background. This is Theorem 19 on page 53 of Burton W. Jones, *The Arithmetic Theory of Quadratic Forms.* Somewhat better tables and instructions for computations in J.W.S. Cassels, [Rational Quadratic Forms](http://store.doverpublications.com/0486466701.html), pages 55-60, tables pages 43-44.

As it happens, this form is universal over the integers with integer variable values, which is an extra result over the Hasse-Minkowski stuff over the rationals.

Lots of detail required for all claims except one: the form is anisotropic in $\mathbb Q$ because it is anisotropic in the 3-adic numbers, and it suffices to consider rational integers.

EXERCISE. If
$$  w^2 - 2 x^2 + 3 y^2 - 6 z^2 \equiv 0 \pmod 9,  $$
then $$ w,x,y,z  \equiv 0 \pmod 3. $$

EEDDDIIITTTT, June 26.   The fact that, if $w^2 - 2 x^2 + 3 y^2 - 6 z^2$ integrally represents two numbers, it also integrally represents their product, is an exercise in quaternion multiplication (with evident coefficients). The fact that $w^2 - 2 x^2 + 3 y^2$ integrally represents all positive primes follows from the evident sections $w^2 + y^2 $ when $x=y,$ and $w^2 - 2 x^2$ when $z=0.$ For the primes $q\equiv 3 \pmod 8,$ we do need material from Dickson's 1939 book, where he prefers to write it as $$ w^2 - 2 (-x-3y)^2 + 3 (y+2z)^2 = w^2 + x^2 - 6 y^2.  $$

=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=

[image]

=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=